# QShortcut in console application (no GUI)

Tags: c++, qt, console-application, hotkeys

Is it possible to use QShortcut in a console QCoreApplication? I don't have any QWidget objects to pass to QShortcut's constructor, I want the signal to be emitted when the user presses a key and the console window has focus.

If such approach is not possible what (prefferably portable) alternatives do I have?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is at all possible, because keyboard events in the sense usually used in Qt are delivered to windows/widgets, by the underlying OS windowing system. There's a reason why `QShortcut` *requires* a widget parent.

When you're in the terminal, you have to explicitly read the terminal to get keys.

Fortunately, that's easy to do. Use `QTextStream` to read from `stdin` in a separate thread, and translate interesting keystrokes to signals or events.

Do note, however, that in consoles some special keystrokes won't be delivered to you as-is. It depends a lot on the console, of course.